# Flask rest api using python produces blank screen when accessed through angular httpClient

Tags: python, angular, flask, flask-restful, jsonify

I am trying to build a basic rest api that returns json in flask(python) and trying to host it on heroku so that I can access the api from angular httpClient.
Here's the heroku api

https://testmyak.herokuapp.com/projects

The problem is that on trying to access the api using httpClient in angular, a blank page is displayed.

The angular code has no errors whatsoever because on accessing any other fake api from json-placeholder website and it populated the page perfectly.

./app.py

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/projects')
def projects():
    x=[]
    x.append({"name":"Debal",
              "gender":"male"})
    x.append({"name":"Debdut",
            "gender":"female"})
    return jsonify(x)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

./Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

./requirements.txt

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

And here's the angular side code
./src/app/customer.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from
'@angular/common/http';
import { ICustomer } from './customer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class CustomerService {
    _url:string='https://testmyak.herokuapp.com/projects';

    constructor(private ht:HttpClient) { }
    getCustomers():Observable<ICustomer[]>{
    return this.ht.get<ICustomer[]>(this._url);
  }
}
```

.src/app/customer.ts

```
export interface ICustomer{
    gender:string,
    name:string
}
```

.src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from
'./customer.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'my-app';
    myL:any[];
    constructor(private _s:CustomerService){}
    ngOnInit(){
     this._s.getCustomers().subscribe(data=>this.myL=data);

    }
}
```

./src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomerService } from
'./customer.service'
import { HttpClientModule } from
'@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [CustomerService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please suggest the changes I should make in my code to make the api accessible using httpClient in angular

Comment: where is your angular side code ?

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from
'@angular/common/http';
import { ICustomer } from './customer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class CustomerService {
  _url:string='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/commen>

  constructor(private ht:HttpClient) { }
  getCustomers():Observable<ICustomer[]>{
   return this.ht.get<ICustomer[]>(this._url);
  }
}         //I was using the url to check if other fake apis were working and they were

Comment: add angular code to question too..

Comment: This is the customer.service.ts file

Comment: Ok am adding angular code

Comment: You need to enable `CORS policy` to server side api, angular httpClient when request your server, serve api blocks this request because, origin is different from api server. you need to enable cors at your api side.

Comment: could you recommend how I can enable CORS policy in python flask and host it on heroku ?

Comment: and define router method for `/project` in api like `@app.route("/projects", methods=["GET"])`

Comment: To enable CORS... before `return jsonify(x)` this statement inside api, do like this.. `response = jsonify(x); response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); return response;`

Comment: or you can install following package... `pip install flask-cors`. after installing it, add this to api def method `@cross_origin()
def projects():`

Comment: Omygod thank you so so so so much the code works. THANK YOU YOU'RE THE BEST. I'm new to stackoverflow can I give you awards or something?